# How can I spawn and drag 2d object from a Canvas button?

Tags: c#, 2d, scene2d, spawning

I want to create and drag an object from canvas button to scene. How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? With what are you stuck?

Comment: i am new to unity i don't know how should i do it.